# Execute statement in mysql if condition

Tags: mysql

i am having an issue in following query. Eveytime query runs into success condition, it directly prints the statement instead of executing. I am struck in this and i am not sure how to fix it. can anyone guide me how to fix following query

```
SELECT IF(
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
                WHERE table_name = 'user_details'
                AND table_schema = 'user_details'
        ) = 0 AND
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE table_name = 'mobile_consumer'
                AND table_schema = DATABASE()
                AND column_name IN ('payment_ref', 'pp', 'tt')
        ) = 3,
        "Select * from users_details",
        "Select 0"
)
```

Sql Output for above query is shown as "select * from users_details", but what i want is that that statement should execute and display rows of the table. any suggestions??

Comment: If course it is. Your select statement isn't a "statement", it's a string. It won't be executed. Research stored procedures/functions.

Comment: What result are you expecting when your code is telling the mysql to display "select * from users_details" message if the first count = 0 and the second is = 3 otherwise just return "select 0" message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you forgot to use, `THEN` clause in your code. Also that you have written your statements to be executed in `IF` block where it should be written in `THEN` block.
Another thing is that you have written your queries in " ", that makes them a simple string that will be printed as they are, instead write them without quotes and if you need to isolate them from rest of the code, use parenthesis. Your updated code is as given below.

```
IF
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
           WHERE table_name = 'user_details'
           AND table_schema = 'user_details'
   ) = 0
   AND
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE table_name = 'mobile_consumer'
           AND table_schema = DATABASE()
           AND column_name IN ('payment_ref', 'pp', 'tt')
   ) = 3

Then
    (Select * from users_details)
ELSE
    (Select 0)
END IF
```

Alternatively you can try using case statement to evaluate your conditions if you have multiple statements to execute against multiple conditions.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 
        count1 = 0 AND count2 = 3 
    THEN 
        (Select * from users_details)
    ELSE
        (Select 0)
    END

FROM
(
    SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE table_name = 'user_details' AND table_schema = 'user_details') AS count1,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'mobile_consumer' AND table_schema = DATABASE() AND column_name IN ('payment_ref', 'pp', 'tt')) AS count2
) 
    AS counts
```

Please mark accepted if it resolved your problem.

Comment: my problem is fixed, but i tried same with update command in another scenarion

Then
    (update users_details set hash= '32cdsfd235454df' where id = 324)
ELSE
    (Select 0)
END IF

But it is throwing error "sql query syntax error near, update users_details". update command does not work for this scenario??

Comment: Can you share complete ```IF ELSE END IF``` statement. Sometimes actual error is caused by something left or right of the pointed position.

Comment: SELECT
CASE WHEN
count1 = 20 
THEN
(UPDATE mobile_consumer set hash = 123 where id = 1 )
ELSE
(Select 0)
END

FROM
(
        SELECT
        (SELECT
                        COUNT(*)
                        FROM
                        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                        WHERE TABLE_NAME
                        = 'mobile_consumer' AND table_schema = 'prime') AS count1
)
AS counts

Comment: I don't see a problem in this statement. If previous comment you finished your statement with ```END IF``` that means you were using ```IF``` to evaluate your condition rather than ```CASE```. Anyways both should work perfectly if you did not mix the syntax of ```IF``` and ```CASE```. Is it still causing the same problem?

Comment: yes, if i replpace update with any select statement, it works fine. But for updates it throws error